# How do I correctly autoload classes OS-safe with namespaces?

Tags: php, path, namespaces, autoload

I am looking for the cleanest, most elegant way to build OS-safe path strings in PHP 8 and include them in my autoload function, without `str_replace()` or `substr()`, if possible.

I have a file structure like this:

```
NameOfProject
├──(...)
├──src
|  ├──Controller
|  |  └──(...)
|  ├──Helper
|  |  └──(...)
|  ├──Model
|  |  └──(...)
|  ├──View
|  |  └──(...)
└──index.php
```

Every class in the `src` folder is namespaced accordingly, for example `NameOfProject\src\Controller`.
I want to autoload every class, using the `spl_autoload_register()` function.

This is my code:

```php
<?php
//index.php

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
  include
    dirname(__FILE__, 2)
    .'/'
    .str_replace('\\', '/', $class)
    .'.php';
});
```

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to avoid the `str_replace()`, but without it, the concatenation of the path string doesn't work, because `$class` always returns the namespace (with backslash) and not the actual path.

I have read that PHP already transforms forward slashes `/` to `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` within functions, but I think I remember having an issue with using just forward slashes in the past.

If the `str_replace()` has to be there, maybe using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is in order? Like so:

```php
str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class)
```

I have also considered the option to strip the class name from `$class`, but this, too, requires an "ugly" `substr()`:

```php
$class = substr($class, strrpos($class, "\\") + 1);
```

Comment: *"would this already work on Windows"* Windows accepts `/` as a directory separator, so yes.

Comment: @Olivier: Thanks, but the question in regards to Windows was more because of the `realpath()`, which will return backslashes on Windows, and I fear that concatenating that with forward slashes will result in a `false` return of the outer `realpath()`. Any insight on this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use `realpath()` in the first place?

Comment: @Olivier: Even without the use of `realpath()`, other functions like `dirname()` also return backslashes on Windows. I assumed that would be a problem, but apparently Windows itself doesn't care whether or not you mix backslash and forward slash in the same path. So I suppose that is one thing that i can clean up - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your code structure is very neat, you can just use the default autoload implementation, see notes in [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php):

```
set_include_path('parent folder of NameOfProject');
spl_autoload_register();
```

This method will try to load the class `NameOfProject\src\Controller\MyController` from `nameofproject/src/controller/mycontroller.php`.

Comment: Yeah, I read that! I would love to implement it, but since my namespaces are like `NameOfProject\src\Controller`, the `'path-to-src-folder'` will make `spl_autoload_register()` look in `path-to-src-folder/NameOfProject/src/Controller/` and such. Am I using namespaces wrong?

Comment: The naming is a little strange, but just set the include path to the parent folder of NameOfProject.

Comment: The default include path is actually the parent folder of NameOfProject, so in theory, it should already work without setting a custom include path. But it still gives me a PHP Fatal error for the first Class usage that I was trying to use. `var_dump(get_include_path())` results in that parent folder path.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "NameOfProject\src\Controller\MyController" not found in path-to-index.php

Both with vanilla `spl_autoload_register()` as well as with your suggested `set_include_path()`

Comment: Try to hard coding `set_include_path` and make sure the class file has namespaces and the class defined. You can put an `exit`/`throw` call in the beginning of the class file, so that you know whether the file is included correctly.

Comment: The absolute path for my project is something like `/home/myName/some/other/things/NameOfProject`. I have tried `set_include_path('/home/myName/some/other/things/');`, `spl_autoload_extensions('.php')`, still the same error like above. The namespaces are exactly like the folder structure, only using the custom `spl_autoload_register()` with the anonymous function that does `include '/home/myName/some/other/things/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $class).'.php';` works so far.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed this note: _this function will LOWERCASE the class names its looking for_, I don't encounter the issue since I am working on Windows, so you need to rename the folders and files if you want to use this method on linux.

Comment: Sadly, renaming all the files and folders is not an option, i want them to be camelcase. So far it looks like I can't use the default `spl_autoload_register()` without custom arguments, if I want it to work on Linux. :(